# AlarmReceiver - get instance of a running activity and call a method using forName

Tags: java, android, reflection, cordova

I am wanting to create a plugin I can share and reuse easily, but as such I won't know the package or activity name for the main application.  So far, I can get all of this information from code.  My problem is that I have receivers which need to call a method on the main application activity if it's running.  Here's where I am so far:

- My application creates an alarm, and I am saving the name of the app activity in the shared preferences (this works):

  ```
  PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
  String packageClassName = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName()).getComponent().getClassName();
  // store the packageClassName in shared prefs
  ```
- Then, in my alarm receiver, I am able to retrieve the class name successfully. I then iterate over all running tasks to see if an activity with the same name is running.  This is working without issue.
- If the activity is found in the list of running tasks, I need to call a method on the activity instance.  This is where I am stuck - I keep getting an `object is not an instance of class` error on the `invoke`.  I am using reflection (try/catch blocks removed for brevity):

  ```
  // get packageClassName from shared prefs
  // loop over running tasks (ActivityManager -> getRunningTasks)
  // if a tasks "topActivity" matches my packageClassName, then proceed...
  Class<?> appClass = Class.forName( packageClassName );
  Method isActiveMethod = appClass.getMethod( "isAppActive" );
  // The following doesn't work b/c "activity" is not an instance of my app
  Boolean isActive = (Boolean)isActiveMethod.invoke( activity );
  ```

Comment: `isAppActive` has to be a method defined by the class of `activity`. Is that the case?

Comment: yes. I was trying not to state the obvious in an effort to keep the question short(er).  In the very last line, the `activity` needs to be an instance of my application activity.  I updated that part of the code to be more clear (read the comments).